# How to copy an envelope through API, carrying over documents and signers?

Tags: docusignapi

In my DocuSign integration, I would like to provide users with the option to create an envelope similar to an existing envelope. I would use templates to accomplish this, but the documents and signers in each envelope can be wildly different.

I noticed in the DocuSign website that the option to "Create a Copy" is available (shown in screenshot below), which does exactly what I need it to do. It creates a new draft envelope, pre-filled with all of the documents and signers from the original envelope.

[image: Create a Copy option is available]

However, I've searched the API reference, DocuSign support center, and docusignapi tag on Stack Overflow with no luck on accomplishing this programmatically. Does anyone know of a call that can accomplish this "Create a Copy" action, or do I have to get creative and reconstruct the envelope from scratch?

Comment: Hi @Austin-kilduff ,Did you find endpoint to clone envelope?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Create a Copy is making calls to get the documents and recipients and then making the call(s) to create the draft envelope.

Comment: Did you try this? I go through api documentation,didn't found any endpoint to clone envelope directly

Comment: POST to the create envelope end point In the body, include the envelope ID you're trying to copy as the value of "envelopeId".

Also include a status. If you want it to auto-send, use "sent", if you want a draft that you can then open and edit, use "created".

Comment: but tab properties and not getting populated ..anyways I have to iterate each property and populate data..